# Why can't I use my openid with HTTPS? Why does it have to be HTTP? Is it because my HTTPS cert is from cacert?

Tags: bug, openid, login, ssl

Today I tried to add the following openid to my stackoverflow account: `https://thejh.net`. However, it failed with this error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

Just `thejh.net` works fine. Could this be because your servers don't accept cacert SSL certificates? If so, how about adding cacert to your list of trusted CAs?

Comment: That site only works because *you* included their root cert...[no major browser or OS includes their root cert](http://wiki.cacert.org/InclusionStatus).  Given that, I'm not really comfortable trusting it either.

Comment: I agree, @Nick, but *maybe* you don't have to trust it? Maybe it would be sufficient that the server just does the SSL/encryption part, leaving the certificate trust steps only being handled by the browser? (If an untrusted certificate of a man-in-the-middle's fake OpenID provider makes the browser stop, and hence would not complete the authentication chain, then what harm could have been done if your server would have been sending things to the faked OpenID provider?) Just thinking out loud here; it surely doesn't feel good to relax security in part of the chain.

Comment: @NickCraver: I would consider Debian to be a major distribution.

Comment: @thejh - it has quite a few users...but percentage-wise we're still talking a insignificant amount of trust for this CA.

Comment: @Arjan - how do we know we're talking to the right server?  We're being thrown a red flag that something is wrong with who we're talking to, that they're not presenting a valid cert.  We *need* to stop when that happens, otherwise what's the point of SSL trust?

Comment: Sure, @Nick, but HTTPS is both certificate trust and SSL encryption. Indeed you would not know you're talking to the right server, but I'm wondering how bad that is, since the same trust validation is done in some other steps of the chain. (That said, I guess I would do the same as you.)