# Wrong LiveJournal OpenID URL generated during login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid, ssl

I've just had several delightful moments of "oh crap I can't use my account anymore." I even telecommuted to work to use my office PC where I'm still logged in to SO to write this question, but then I figured it by accident.

So I had to clear my browser cache.
Then I tried to log in with my usual LiveJournal OpenID (which I do by clicking the pencil icon and typing just my LJ user name in the small box), but Stack Overflow would keep saying in a red box:

> No OpenID endpoint found

I tried several times, one time I instead got that in a similar red box:

> OpenIdIdentifierRequired

but otherwise it was consistently the former.

Turned out, when I enter my LJ user ID into the small box, the big box is auto-populated with `https://<correct path to LJ OpenID>`, and that link fails. To fix it, I had to go 'Back' and manually change `https://` to `http://`, only then it logged me in.

**Please fix the auto-population to use `http://` in the first place.**

Possibly related:
[Why can't I use my openid with HTTPS? Why does it have to be HTTP? Is it because my HTTPS cert is from cacert?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171194/147640)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Didn't expect an openId provider that doesn't support https - in particular a large one such as LiveJournal.

This default has been changed and will be with you in the next build (rev 2014.3.13.1453, meta rev 2014.3.13.2051).